# how can I use if-else statement inline in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this code from a tutorial video , but first of all I didn't get the purpose of `clk` function and how it is related to `h1` tag and that trinary operator.

second , how can I use normal `if-else` instead of ternary operator and not only for adding class but changing its `style` too.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./App.css";

function App(){
  let [isRed,setRed] = useState(false);
  function clk(){
    setRed(true);
  }
  return(
        <div>
           <h1 className={isRed?"red":""}>Change My Color</h1>
           <button onClick={clk}>ClickHere</button>
        </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: THe `clk` function is the click handler. It runs when you click on the button. In there you can freely use if else blocks and set state variables as a result. You can also put your if else block directly before the `return` line, after the `clk` function.

Comment: @ChrisG can you please do that with code ? I don't know how to do it

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/uLcd1a4x/ (also, and I'm sorry to say this: the answers here are all mostly useless. nobody properly read your question it seems)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for help  but you didn't use `export default App;` is doing that is bad practice?

Comment: Is there any specific reason *why* you want to use an if/else, instead of a ternary? Simply giving you code fragments showing how it could be done, might not at all be beneficial if it guides you on a track of bad practices. In JSX ternaries are very common, so avoiding them will be very inconvenient.

Comment: @Yoshi you sure that ternaries are common ? , it's making harder for me to understand it compared to normal if-else , because in vanilla JS it was totally different story  and I didn't use ternaries so much

Comment: It's not bad practice at all, but in my fiddle I'm not using multiple modules so I don't have to export anything. If your react app has an index.js file that imports and renders App, then you very much *need* that export line.

Comment: Regarding ternary expressions, they are easier to understand if you don't smush everything together: `isRed ? "red" : ""` I recommend not wasting any more time with a potentially outdated or bad video tutorial and using the official React tutorial instead.

Comment: @JSXStarter Yeah, I'm pretty sure ternaries are very common where appropriate. Especially when you want to conditionally render parts of your JSX., you'll encounter them in a lot.

Comment: Part of the reason why you're getting downvoted is that you're trying to learn React without a solid understanding of core JavaScript, and it shows ... :P

Comment: @ChrisG what does `isRed ? "red" : " "` mean in English ?

Comment: It's an expression like `3 + 4 * 5`. The value of that expression is `23`. The value of a ternary expression depends on the first part. It's `condition ? conditionIsTrue : conditionIsFalse`

Comment: @ChrisG do you have resource to understand core of javascript ? because I was working good with vanilla JS but reactJS .... just struggle ...

Comment: The main resource you need is time. Practice. I've been writing JS since the 90s. As for an actual resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @Yoshi I didn't experience a lot problem with vanilla JS , from basic functions to arrays to I don't know intersection observers ... everything , what exactly you mean by being fluent?

Comment: I believe that you want to use a memoized value. Especially if you want to set a class name; along with various style values as you stated in your question. See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408863/1762224) below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use `if-else` in inline jsx but there exists some workarounds and you can choose whichever you want.
**variant 1:**

```
if(isRed){
  const header = <h1 className='red' style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' ... }}>Change My Color</h1>
} else {
  const header = <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' ... }}>Change My Color</h1>
}

return (
  <div>
    {header}
    <button onClick={clk}>ClickHere</button>
  </div>
);
```

**variant 2: (but still ternary opeartor used)**

```
if(isRed){
} else {
  const header = 
}

return (
  <div>
    {isRed ? ( 
      <h1 className='red' style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' ... }}>Change My Color</h1>
    ) : (
      <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' ... }}>Change My Color</h1>
    )}
    <button onClick={clk}>ClickHere</button>
  </div>
);
```

There is no other way to replace ternary operator with `if-else` statement

Comment: Or you can just set a bunch of attribute variables in the if-else block and use them in the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by applying this

```
<h1 className={`${isRed ? "red" : ""}`}>Change My Color</h1>
```

Or

```
{
 isRed ? (
   <h1 className={"red"}>Change My Color</h1>
 ) : (
      <h1 className={"other"}>Change My Color</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: it is still trinary operator

Comment: OP is asking how to **not** use ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a memo to your `<h1>` element that gets calculated when that particular state changes. Please note that JSX is not JavaScript. It may appear similar, and you may be able to use 99% of the syntax, but there are differences.

You can learn more about memoized values here: [React / Docs / Hooks / useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```js
const { useMemo, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  let [isRed, setRed] = useState(false);
  let [isBlue, setBlue] = useState(false);
  
  const onClickRed  = (e) => setRed(!isRed);   // onclick callback
  const onClickBlue = (e) => setBlue(!isBlue); // onclick callback

  const headerPropsRed = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Red updated!');
    let props = {};
    if (isRed) {
      props = {
        ...props,
        className: 'red',
        style: {
          ...props.style,
          fontStyle: 'italic'
        }
      }
    } 
    return props;
  }, [ isRed ]);
  
  const headerPropsBlue = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Blue updated!');
    let props = {};
    if (isBlue) {
      props = {
        ...props,
        className: 'blue',
        style: {
          ...props.style,
          fontStyle: 'italic'
        }
      }
    } 
    return props;
  }, [ isBlue ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 {...headerPropsRed}>Change My Color</h1>
      <button onClick={onClickRed}>Click Here</button>
      <h1 {...headerPropsBlue}>Change My Color</h1>
      <button onClick={onClickBlue}>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3em !important; }

h1 { font-size: 1em; }

.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: no actually I didn't forget it I just didn't post as snippet because it's not so necessary  just a class with `background-color:red` property in it . I just want to get rid of trinary operator and I want to know its relation with `useState`

Comment: @JSXStarter when you change the state, the value change will cause the render function to get called again.

Comment: @JSXStarter I believe you want to use something like `useMemo`. I updated my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your elements inside of a {} makes it interpreted as js code
`
{if(isRed) return < h1>...< /h1> else return < h1>...< /h1>}

`
should work.. Maybe you can use the same inside the class attribute, but it will be hard to read.

As for the click function, it is setting the value of isRed to true. This will create the reactive change to your style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) working like this:

```js
if(condition) ? "True part here" : "else part here (false part)"
```

Use case example :

```js
const id = 1;
if(id === 1) ? "You are on right place" : "Sorry please check"
```

Comment: Consider using code formatting if you want to provide an answer so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Ok will try in next solution @SmileyProd.

Comment: I edited your answer so you can see how you could do it